# How to fix "Failed to start Crash recovery kernel arming" when can not enter the system directly?

Tags: linux, centos-7

I run CentOS 7 in the Parallels Desktop. I was stuck on booting and could not enter the system.

When booting, it shows the info:

```
Failed to start Crash recovery kernel arming.
See `systemctl status kdump.service` for details.
```

I searched the problem on the web. Many posts said that it can solved by changing `crashkenerl=auto` to `crashkenerl=128M` and so on.

However, I can not edit the corresponding file before I log in. Besides, I find it need the system iso to enter rescue mode but I don't have one. (If have an alternative simple solution, nobody want to download a system iso.)

Answer (score 4):

I solved it after 2 hours struggle without downloading a system ISO (because I want to solve it as simply as possible). 
Here is my solution:

1. Boot the system
2. Press <kbd>e</kbd> for edit mode
3. Use the nav keys to find `crashkernel=auto`
4. Change it to `crashkernel=128M` or `crashkernel=256M`
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to boot
6. Change `crashkernel=auto` in the file `/etc/grub2.cfg` as in step 4.
   (for this, I use the ssh under the help of my prior configure)
7. Reboot

Comment: It should be noted that the size of the crashkernel is depdent upon system memory size. Please check size guide before performing the edit: https://www.golinuxhub.com/2018/08/how-to-configure-and-install-kdump-rhel7-crashkernel/

Answer (score 1):

to permanently modify the grub you must, with root user,:

- vi /etc/default/grub
- find   "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX" end replace  "crashkernel=auto" whith "crashkernel=128M
  or "crashkernel=256M"
- save and exit
- grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
- reboot machine

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the amount of reserved memory to be variable, depending on the total amount of installed memory.

The syntax for variable memory reservation is: `crashkernel=range1:size1,range2:size2`.

Example: `crashkernel=512M-2G:64M,2G-:128M`

[Source](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/kernel_administration_guide/kernel_crash_dump_guide)